# (psycopg2.OperationalError) Invalid - opcode

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, netezza

I am trying to connect to Netezza using `SQLalchemy.create_engine()`. The reason I want to use SQLAlchmey is because I want to be able to read and write through pandas dataframe.

What works is as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=NZDWW')
df2 = pd.read_sql(Query,conn)
```

Above code runs fine. But in order to write `df` dataframe to the Netezza, I need to use the function `to_sql()`, which needs SQLAlchemy. This is what my code looks like:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
username = os.getenv('REDSHIFT_USER')
password = os.getenv('REDSHIFT_PASS')
DATABASE = "SHP_TARGET"
HOST = "Netezza1"
PORT = 5480
conn_str = "postgresql://"+username+":"+password+"@"+HOST+':'+str(PORT)+'/'+DATABASE
engine3 = create_engine(conn_str)
df = pd.read_sql(Query, engine3)
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) Invalid - opcode
Invalid - opcodeInvalid packet length (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Any leads will be much appreciated. thanks.

Database: Netezza
Python version: 3.6
OS: Windows

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlalchemy` dialect for Postges isn't compatible with Netezza.

The error you're receiving is the `psycopg2` module, which facilitates the connection, complaining that it can't make sense of what the server is "saying", basically.

There [appears to be a dialect for Netezza](https://github.com/deontologician/netezza_sqlalchemy) though. You may want to try that out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the formal dialect for Netezza has been released.

It can be used as documented here - https://github.com/IBM/nzalchemy#prerequisites

Example

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib import parse_quote_plus

# assumes NZ_HOST, NZ_USER, NZ_PASSWORD are set
import os

params = parse_quote_plus(f"DRIVER=NetezzaSQL;SERVER={os['NZ_HOST']};"
            f"DATABASE={os['NZ_DATABASE']};USER={os['NZ_USER'};"
            f"PASSWORD={os['NZ_PASSWORD']}")
engine = create_engine(f"netezza+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}", 
            echo=True)
```